# GCDAsyncUdpSocket does not compile for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, udp, asyncsocket

I use this library: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

There are examples for TCP on the iphone but not UDP. I think that everything should be just the same. Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class GCDAsyncUdpSocket;

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController
{
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket;
}
```

.m:

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h"

static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;

@implementation ThirdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}
```

But when compiling I get the errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog",
>
> referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ThirdViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDTTYLogger",
>   referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ThirdViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDAsyncUdpSocket",
>   referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ThirdViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

What is wrong? Examples from the library compiled without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to link CFNetwork.framework or if have it you're propably working on Automatic Reference Counter, turon off ARC for GCDAsyncUdpSocket using -fno-objc-arc

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't use ARC. About the CFNetwork.framework I forgot, now added a link but the error remained.

Comment: now you propably have problem with DDTTYLogger, do you have AvFoundation library in you project? Did you link header files of DDLog to your compile sources ?

Comment: You may also need to link Security.framework. 

And for any iOS beginners (Xcode 4.3.2), linking is done by looking on the files menu (left pane) and clicking on the main project at the top of the list...
Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries (click the + symbol at the bottom then select your desired libs from the pop-up list).
Ah, and add the gcdasyncudpsocket.m and gcdasyncsocket.m files to the Compiled Sources list on the same page (build phases).

See the following link:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

(Build Phases >> Link Binary With Libraries) Add CocoaLumberjack as optional dependency.